# Can I download a complete folder from Inspect Console?

Tags: html, browser, console

When I did inspect on some image from a web page, I found they are in a folder. I can download each one individually, but wondering if I can download the whole folder at once?

[image]

Comment: You could try an addon like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-all-images/ifipmflagepipjokmbdecpmjbibjnakm?hl=en or this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-all-images/nnffbdeachhbpfapjklmpnmjcgamcdmm?hl=en but it probably saves everything on the page and not just the specific folder. I don't see any way of doing it natively on just a selected folder. There's also a project on Github that you could try: https://gist.github.com/tobek/a17fa9101d7e28ddad26

Comment: That works great. Bring all the pictures, but the one I want start with "Portrait_" so were easy to get. Thanks @AStombaugh

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked! :)